# How to play back CSV data in real time?

Tags: javascript

I am creating telemetry software for driving games. I am currently saving the received data as a CSV (as it is web-based and can be downloaded without needing a server) I save each packet with an epoch timestamp the packet was received. The time delta between each packet is not fixed and is dependent on how quickly the game can push the data.

I just can't think of how I might even approach this: my current idea would be to check each line of the CSV for its timestamp and see if it is the same as the playback time the webpage thinks it is at, and if so update the data entries on the page, if not check the next line.

Comment: I think what you should be concerned with is the time difference between successive rows.  If you're controlling the animation loop, you can do it by setting timeout to the next update equal to the time delta to the next row.

Comment: Unfortunately, each packet does not have a consistent delta between itself and the next one.

Comment: why would it need that? you check the delta to the next line, then schedule a setTimeout for that many milliseconds into the future, _bearing in mind_ that you don't ever want to schedule timeouts less than 4ms into the future, to avoid timeout throttling, and _corrected for drift_ (i.e. you don't just track "how many ms in the future the message needs to run" but also how many milliseconds since the start have passed according to the CVS data you already processed, and the actual clock time, so that you can correct CVS deltas when a timeout took longer than you scheduled it for)

Comment: Agree with @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans about short time intervals and occasional "dead reckoning" with total elapsed time. The idea assumes varying intervals. For large time gaps, the receiving side -- since it knows future state -- could even insert rows with interpolated state (and interpolated timings).